# How can I log into an azure VM via my Mac?

Tags: remote-desktop

Recently switched to Macs.

I have some Azure VMs. In Windows, I just need to boot up the remote connections dialog, put in the server and credentials and it should log me in.

Is there a similar sort of thing for OSX as well?

Answer (score 1):

You just need a Remote Desktop Client.

Microsoft has an official one called Microsoft Remote Desktop, that is free. [It's available on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417).

There are other alternatives as well, such as [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net).